# How to compare every value from a column from one df with every value from a column of another df in R? dfs with different row numbers

Tags: r, for-loop, left-join, subset

Which box fits in which basket by also taking into consideration the priority of the boxes and baskets?

**df.boxes** has the following columns:
**boxID** - the name of the box
**boxX** - the size of the box in the X dimension
**boxY** - the size of the box in the Y dimension
**importance** - which box should be assigned to a basket first. like a priority -  555 most important (with the highest priority), 111 least important (with the lowest priority)

**df.basket** has the following columns:
**basketID** - the name of the basket
**basketX** - the size of the basket in the X dimension
**basketY** - the size of the basket in the Y dimension
**priorityOfSelection** - which basket should be first filled with a box.  1 - highest priority, 7 - lowest priority

for example, box1  doesn't fit in the basket with the highest priority, a.k.a basket 1, so it moves down to the next basket with priorityOfSelection "2" and stores its name in a new column "boxes" of df.basket.

I have a though, first I order the two data frames based on their "importance", "priorotyOfSelection" and compare the size of the boxes to the size of the basket and if there is a match I assign the name of the box to the corresponding basket. In this order of thinking I am trying to create nested for-loop - unsuccessfully, as you may see.

Could anyone point out what and where I do wrong or direct me to an alternative approach, that would be also highly appreciated?

reprex

```
 df.boxes <-structure(list(boxID = c("box 1", "box 2", "box 3", "box 4", "box 5"), 
                                  boxX = c(600,450, 400, 350, 200), 
                                  boxY = c(600, 400, 450, 500, 300),
                                  importance = c(555, 444, 333, 222, 111) 
                                  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df.basket <- structure(list(basketID = c("basket 1", "basket 2", "basket 3","basket 4", "basket 5", "basket 6", "basket 8"), 
                            basketX = c(500,650, 500,200, 450, 500,300),
                            basketY = c(450,650, 500,300,450,500, 300),
                            priorityOfSelection = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7) 
                            ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

attempt:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df.boxes)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df.basket)){
  df.basket$box[j] <- ifelse((df.boxes$boxX[i] <= df.basket$basketX[j] | df.boxes$boxY[i] <= df.basket$basketX[j]) & (df.boxes$boxX[i] <= df.basket$basketY[j] | df.boxes$boxY[i] <= df.basket$basketY[j]), 
                                df.boxes$boxID[i], "none")
  }
}
```

desired output:
[image]

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You could use something like this to determine which baskets a box will fit in and then since they are in order of priority just take the first one that it will fit in. `which(df.basket[,"basketX"]>df.boxes[2,"boxX"] & df.basket[,"basketY"]>df.boxes[2,"boxY"])[1]`

Comment: This works to automate it. The problem being that it overwrites baskets that have already been used.  `for (i in 1:nrow(df.boxes)){
  df.basket[which(df.basket$basketX>df.boxes[i,"boxX"] & df.basket$basketY>df.boxes[i,"boxY"])[1], "box"]<-df.boxes[i,"boxID"]
}`

Comment: thank you for writing! When I run your code individually(from the first comment) it works correct up to the third box and the automated version gives me false assignment of boxes to baskets.

Comment: That's caused by it overwriting. If you set the box column to 0's then add that as a condition so it wont overwrite anything it should fix it.`df.basket[,"box"]<-0
for (i in 1:nrow(df.boxes)){
  df.basket[which(df.basket$basketX>=df.boxes[i,"boxX"] & df.basket$basketY>=df.boxes[i,"boxY"] & df.basket$box==0)[1], "box"]<-df.boxes[i,"boxID"]
}
` This gives me the same results as your example. It gives 0 instead of none for unused baskets, but you could easily change that if you want. This is getting to be pretty close to what @AllanCameron suggested.

Comment: yes, indeed, thank you @Tanner33, I get the expected result now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up an extra column in `df.boxes` to record whether the box has been "used" or not, you can do it this way:

```r
df.basket$box <- character(nrow(df.basket))
df.boxes$used <- logical(nrow(df.boxes))

for(i in sort(df.basket$priorityOfSelection))
{
  fits <- which(df.boxes$boxX <= df.basket$basketX[i] &
                df.boxes$boxY <= df.basket$basketY[i] &
                df.boxes$used == FALSE)

  df.basket$box[which(df.basket$priorityOfSelection == i)] <- 
    paste("box", fits[which.max(df.boxes$importance[fits])])
  df.boxes$used[fits[which.max(df.boxes$importance[fits])]] <- TRUE
}

df.basket$box[df.basket$box == "box "] <- "none"

df.basket
#>   basketID basketX basketY priorityOfSelection   box
#> 1 basket 1     500     450                   1 box 2
#> 2 basket 2     650     650                   2 box 1
#> 3 basket 3     500     500                   3 box 3
#> 4 basket 4     200     300                   4 box 5
#> 5 basket 5     450     450                   5  none
#> 6 basket 6     500     500                   6 box 4
#> 7 basket 8     300     300                   7  none
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: wow, thank you! it seems easy and yet it is not! One thing though, it is possible to rotate the box inside the basket. I extended your `fits` vector:  `fits <- which(((df.boxes$boxX <= df.basket$basketX[i] | df.boxes$boxX <= df.basket$basketY[i] ) & (df.boxes$boxY <= df.basket$basketX[i]| df.boxes$boxY <= df.basket$basketY[i])) & df.boxes$used == FALSE)`
and so far it still gives the same result as yours and as the desired one :) Thank you very much! All the best, -

Comment: Be careful with the "or" statements. The way you have it written a box fits in a basket as long as one side of the basket is longer than both sides of the box. You need something more like (x <= x "and" y <= y "or" x <= y "and" y <= x).

Comment: `fits <- which(((df.boxes$boxX <= df.basket$basketX[i] & df.boxes$boxY <= df.basket$basketY[i] ) | (df.boxes$boxY <= df.basket$basketX[i] & df.boxes$boxX <= df.basket$basketY[i])) & df.boxes$used == FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a late submission with "pure `for` looping" and `if`'s with no extra columns.
Under the assumption that what you are basically trying to achieve is pushing the boxes from top to bottom into the (priority ordered) baskets (list)

```
df.basket$box <- NA
for (i in seq.int(df.boxes$boxID)){
  for (j in seq.int(df.basket$basketID)){
    if(is.na(df.basket$box[j])){ 
        if (all( c(df.basket$basketX[j], df.basket$basketY[j]) -
                 c(df.boxes$boxX[i], df.boxes$boxY[i]) >= 0)){
            df.basket$box[j] <- df.boxes$boxID[i] 
  break
        }
    }
  }
}
df.basket$box[is.na(df.basket$box)] <- "none" 
df.basket 

    basketID basketX basketY priorityOfSelection   box
1 basket 1     500     450                   1 box 2
2 basket 2     650     650                   2 box 1
3 basket 3     500     500                   3 box 3
4 basket 4     200     300                   4 box 5
5 basket 5     450     450                   5  none
6 basket 6     500     500                   6 box 4
7 basket 8     300     300                   7  none
```

For sure not as elegant as  the solution by '@Allan Cameron' but also a possible approach, if you wanna grasp the `for` loop approach you started out with in your own attempt a bit better.

Comment: It is so nice to see my initial approach developed in a way to give the desired output. It may be just the first two lines of code but still, there is a nested for-loop :) Thank you very much!